# Deep linking of website urls does not ask for other apps in intent chooser

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking, intentfilter

I am done deep linking my android app with my website with handling all the URLs. One thing I noticed that after launching the app on play store the `ACTION_VIEW` intent for my website URL does not ask the user to select other apps like chrome or any other browser. Everything else is working perfectly.

I am creating an intent with `ACTION_VIEW` to open my website URL in any other browser if a user wants to open it in the browser app. But what my problem is the intent chooser does not ask for browser apps instead it is again opening directly in my own app. There is no default set for my application and I verified it Manage apps.

The intent creation code is

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        i.data = Uri.parse(internetUrl)
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.select_browser))
        startActivity(chooserIntent)
```

I need my app to ask user to select either browser or my app instead of opening it directly in my app.

The activity intent filter is

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="@string/intent_filter_host_full_site"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have implemented an app link instead of a deep link.

From documentation:

A deep link is an intent filter that allows users to directly enter a specific activity in your Android app. Clicking one of these links might open a disambiguation dialog, which allows the user to select one of multiple apps (including yours) that can handle the given URL. For example, figure 1 shows the disambiguation dialog after the user clicks a map link, asking whether to open the link in Maps or Chrome.

Android App Links are a special type of deep link that allows your website URLs to immediately open the corresponding content in your Android app (without requiring the user to select the app).

---

I guess you did some unnecessary work:

- added `autoVerify="true"` to your intent filter;
- uploaded `https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json` to your web site;

To solve your problem you should reverse the steps listed above.

**IMPORTANT:** After reverse above steps you should uninstall your app and install it again!

Comment: Yes exaclty I have uploaded asselinks.json file. but it is necessary to open the website's link in corresponding app page.

Comment: I just wanted to exclude my app from action_view in case I have manually raised the intent just for the convenience of the user to view in browser

Comment: To open the corresponding app page you can move your intent filter to that activity in the manifest. And you don't need to manually trigger such intent, it's unnecessary because Android handles it for you even if you remove the domain verification.

Comment: I dont have any other activity. My app uses fragments hosted on a single activity. And I really need to manually trigger that intent because I want my users to give an option of viewing same page on browser if something went wrong on the app side.

Comment: Never mind. I want to say that if you follow my instructions you will get desired behavior: when user tap on link system first will invoke chooser dialog through which user able to choose app or browser to handle link.